# wxwidget 2.9.4 build link error under win7 vs2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets

I batch build the wxwidget under vs2010 ultimate and get a error:

```
Build started 2013/3/11 10:41:47.
InitializeBuildStatus:
Touching "vc_mswuddll\stc\stc.unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
All outputs are up-to-date.
ClCompile:
All outputs are up-to-date.
All outputs are up-to-date.
ResourceCompile:
All outputs are up-to-date.
ManifestResourceCompile:
All outputs are up-to-date.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\jack\dev\wx\wxWidgets-2.9.4\build\msw\..\..\lib\vc_dll\stc.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\jack\dev\wx\wxWidgets-2.9.4\lib\vc_dll\wxmsw294ud_stc_vc_custom.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(992,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(stc) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (wxmsw294ud_stc_vc_custom). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\jack\dev\wx\wxWidgets-2.9.4\lib\vc_lib\wxscintillad.lib'
```

I try two times in two different win7 system(build using win7 32bit and win7 64 bit) using a same PC, but this pC is a little old(mading in 2007 years), but I try it under my laptop(made in 2011), with no error. SO I am confused, I check the configure of the stc project. the all the value is same between the laptop and the PC. Could anyone face the same problem or have some idea of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building from the provided solution on visual studio ?

I had a lot of problem with that on wxWidget 2.8.12 and visual studio 2008. It could be because the dependencies between the different projects are not set in visual studio. You end up building a wxWidget lib that depends on wxscintillad before building wxscintillad. wxWidget has the list of project dependencies that you have to set manually on their web site.

Another solution can be to build manually with visual studio command prompt, in the `build\msw\` directory of wxWidget do this:

`nmake -f makefile.vc MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=0 USE_EXCEPTIONS=1 USE_RTTI=1 RUNTIME_LIBS=dynamic CPPFLAGS="/Zc:wchar_t- /EHa" BUILD=release DEBUG_INFO=1`

The debug command line is:

`nmake -f makefile.vc MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=0 USE_EXCEPTIONS=1 USE_RTTI=1 RUNTIME_LIBS=dynamic CPPFLAGS="/Zc:wchar_t- /EHa" DEBUG_INFO=1`

Eventually if you need to clean and start from scratch:

- Delete all folders (NOT FILES) under $WXWIN\wx\build\msw\
- Delete all files under $WXWIN\wx\lib\